# How to turn off Narrator during Windows 10 Setup?

Tags: windows-10

I found a bunch of questions about disabling the narrator in Windows 10. However, they all assume that you've finished installing it.

Somehow, I've managed to turn on narrator **during Windows 10 Setup**, and now I can't seem to turn it off.

How?

Answer (score 3):

caps lock + esc key should do it

Comment: Grr, that was driving me crazy, and there was no obvious UI option to turn it back off... but this keyboard combination did it.

Answer (score 0):

Cortana is used in the latest installer of Win10, you can mute it but not much else when you are installing from the MS provided image. If you have an older installer this will not occur.